# Comparing all cells in 2 different sheets and finding mismatch list isn't working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set with columns from A to AZ. I want to find if any cell value in Columns A & B is found in Columns AA:AZ and I want a list of those unique not found values from all the compared columns.

What I did first is create 2 new sheets to separate the comparison. 1st sheet (SKUReference) which is copied from column A & B. Second sheet is (SKUNewList) which is copied from AA till AZ. I created a 3rd sheet (NotFoundSKU) to have the desired output which is the Not Found values from the comparison.

The data in the 1st sheet (SKUReference) looks like below : 
[image]

The data in the 2nd sheet (SKUNewList) looks like below :
[image]

The issue I'm facing is : 1- the code isn't finding the Mismatches. 2- It's not storing the unique mismatches correctly. 3- It's not generating those mismatches in the 3rd sheet (NotFoundSKU).

```
Sub yg23iwyg()

Dim wst As Worksheet
Dim wet As Worksheet

Set wst = Worksheets.Add
Set wet = Worksheets.Add
Set wrt = Worksheets.Add

wst.Name = "SKUReference"
wet.Name = "SKUNewList"
wrt.Name = "NotFoundSKU"

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Copy _
        Destination:=wst.Cells(1, "A")
    .Range(.Cells(1, "AA"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AZ").End(xlUp)).Copy _
        Destination:=wet.Cells(1, "A")

    'alternate with Union'ed range - becomes a Copy, Paste Special, Values and Formats because of the union
    .Range("AA:AZ").Copy _
        Destination:=wet.Cells(1, "A")
End With

Dim wksMaster As Worksheet, wksSearch As Worksheet
Dim rngMaster As Range, rngSearch As Range

Set wksMaster = Sheets("SKUReference")
Set wksSearch = Sheets("SKUNewList")

With wksMaster
    Set rngMaster = .Range("A1:B100" & .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
End With

With wksSearch
    Set rngSearch = .Range("A1:Y100" & .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
End With

With rngMaster
    For Each cll In rngSearch
        Set c = .Find(cll.Value2, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            'MsgBox cll.Value2 & " not found in the SKU Reference List."
            Sheets("NotFoundSKU").Range("A1") = cll.Value2
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set rngMaster = .Range("A1:B100" & .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)` is concatenating 100 and the last row (I wouldn't use special cells anyway) so could be giving you a very large number indeed. There is nothing in your code to insert "NOT FOUND".

Comment: Thanks, @SJR I didn't realize it was doing that. I was just trying to select the range of cells in this sheet, what should I be doing instead? On the other point, could you suggest how and where to insert that?

Comment: Remove the 100. Isn't the other bit the commented out line?

Comment: I didn't get you, if I remove it, what should be the correct range values?

Comment: Just use `Set rngMaster = .Range("A1:B" & .range("B" & .rows.count).end(xlup).row)`.

Comment: Thank you! Could you suggest how to insert the "NOT FOUND" in Sheets("NotFoundSKU")?

Comment: I don't think I understand what the problem is. Where should the text go? What is your difficulty?

Comment: While searching for wksSearch in rngSearch, if values are not found, they should be printed in the output sheet which is Sheets("NotFoundSKU")

Comment: I've commented out the msgbox because I don't want to see it in msgbox but in the output sheet

Comment: So you are just putting them in A1 so they overwrite and you want them listed?

Comment: Yes. I want to see those values listed in first column in the output sheet which I defined as Sheets("NotFoundSKU")

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which incorporates comments above (to set `rngMaster` and `rngSearch`) and will list values not found in a list going down by finding the first empty cell.

```
Sub yg23iwyg()

Dim wst As Worksheet
Dim wet As Worksheet, c as range, cll as range

Set wst = Worksheets.Add
Set wet = Worksheets.Add
Set wrt = Worksheets.Add

wst.Name = "SKUReference"
wet.Name = "SKUNewList"
wrt.Name = "NotFoundSKU"

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Copy _
        Destination:=wst.Cells(1, "A")
    .Range(.Cells(1, "AA"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AZ").End(xlUp)).Copy _
        Destination:=wet.Cells(1, "A")

    'alternate with Union'ed range - becomes a Copy, Paste Special, Values and Formats because of the union
    .Range("AA:AZ").Copy _
        Destination:=wet.Cells(1, "A")
End With

Dim wksMaster As Worksheet, wksSearch As Worksheet
Dim rngMaster As Range, rngSearch As Range

Set wksMaster = Sheets("SKUReference")
Set wksSearch = Sheets("SKUNewList")

With wksMaster
    Set rngMaster = .Range("A1:B" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With

With wksSearch
    Set rngSearch = .Range("A1:Y" & .Range("Y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With

With rngMaster
    For Each cll In rngSearch
        Set c = .Find(cll.Value2, LookIn:=xlValues) 'i would consider adding more parameters here
        If c Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("NotFoundSKU").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = cll.Value2
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried it. It generate the 3rd sheet "NotFoundSKU" but with first row in A column as empty and then 2nd row having the header available in Sheet SKUNewList. It seems it's not bringing the Not found values.

Comment: That sounds like the values are all found. If you want to exclude headers, start your range at row 2 rather than 1.

Comment: I have made some changes to the code so try again (and had accidentally posted twice).

Comment: Thank you, SJR. I have provided unmatched values to test it so it should pick them as Not Found, but it's not. It doesn't seem to be finding the mismatches between the 2 sheets.

Comment: I found that before we made this change : Set rngMaster = .Range("A1:B" & .range("B" & .rows.count).end(xlup).row) At least the code was working and giving the unmatched values, but now after we did the change, it's doesn't find any.

Comment: Is there as much data in B as A?

Comment: A & B both has data, but usually B has more data. It has to compare all the values in these 2 columns with the other sheet and find what is not found between the 2 sheets.

Comment: Hard for me to tell without knowing your data. Start by specifying all Find parameters.

Comment: I've made changes to the original post and provided pictures. Just an FYI so you don't get confused, the tabs in my excel is from Right>Left